# Combined timer/RTCC

Tags: timer, rtc

I have been using a Maxim DS3231 as a RTCC with its alarms used to "wake up" certain hardware.

Now I need to wake up the hardware periodically, say every hour, so I actually need a timer (not need to take account of ss/mm/hh/day/month/year.)

1. Is there any IC from the family of DS3231 (or similar) that can operate as a timer, precisely that after set interval it makes a pulse on one of their pins?
2. Is there any IC from the family of DS3231 (or similar) that can operate as a timer as above and also as an RTCC?

I made a research in Internet but really did not find anything that suits this requirement.

Comment: This seems to be *exactly* the kind of thing you'd buy a DS3231 for... are you sure it doesn't do that already? While we're at "does that already": your other "certain hardware" doesn't happen to include a microcontroller with an RTC already, doesn't it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your reply Marcus. I see my question may have not been completely clear. Pls see my comment to justme's answer.

Answer (score 1):

For both questions, the DS3231 can already do it, for example repeat an alarm every hour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the point is that to repeat the alarm every hour means that the HW connected to the DS3231 has to set it up. If for any reason it is temporary unavailable to do that, no one will, and consequently, the HW will sleep for ever...

Comment: That seems to be incorrect. The DS3231 datasheet says there's a *match condition* that triggers the alarm, and you can set mask bits so that the time-of-day alarm happens when minutes and seconds match. Yes, your DS3231 can already do what you want.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You still need to set alarms and start the clock after powering the RTC. Guille, yes that is obvious, but that restriction was not included in your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I really thank you for your comment Marcus. You are absolutely rigth. I had not noticed that you can mask the time/day registers of the DS3231. In fact, by disabling the proper registers, I can **cyclically** get the alarm without any need of setting new alarms. I should better read better the data sheet next time, but this requires time; I think one of the scope of the forum (although not the only one) maybe helping users to save time.

Comment: hm, "it uses time": it also requires time to read your question and write answers and comments. Are you implying our time is less worth saving than yours?

Comment: Not at all, but to answer your question rigorously, a trade off analysis should be done, and I am not so sure in that would be worthwhile. I sincerely thank you for your answer and your time. This was my first question in this forum, I am not so experience with its style, but if you think my question was inappropriate please let me know it, I will try to avoid it. Maybe you also may just consider to avoid answering, is you deem the question does not deserve spending your time. Anyway, thanks again!